# how to design the div tag with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make multiple boxes like below with bootstrap
[image]

all the images were the same height, but different widths, so I tried to use a grid system, but it doesn't work. What does that "doesnt work" mean? If I put col-md-4 for image1, and put col-md-2 for following txt, put col-md-3 for image2, all the grid system widths and heights adjust automatically, so all the heights of the images are different.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) comes to mind, but there apparently is also a horizontal one: [masonryHorizontal](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonryhorizontal.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this help me a lot!!

Comment: Added my comment as the answer. Please accept and upvote if it has helped!

Answer (score 1):

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) comes to mind, but there apparently is also a horizontal one: [masonryHorizontal](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonryhorizontal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a containing element to house the grid system? For example Bootstrap 3 uses:

```
<div class="container">
 ...
</div>
```

Additionally, the Bootstrap grid system scales up to **12 columns** as the viewport size increases. If you want three even columns on the top row try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Check out this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/andrewjst/3gtst4c2/ -  It has the same column set you have shown in your picture.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-4" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-4" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-4" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3" style="border-style: solid;">.col-xs-6 col-xs-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```